# Unable to resolve expo-font. Expo modules does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My **package.json** looks like this, and I am getting an error that unable to resolve expo-font. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add the error as image, but paste it in your question as (formatted) text

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution to this.
`rm -rf /tmp/metro-cache`
This resolves the issue.